# C# to JSON Structuring Nested Dictionaries

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save information to JSON in a nested form like this:

(apologies for the ugly wall of code, I just want to get across how I'm trying to structure this)

```
"Data":{
  "001":{
    "01":{
      "1":{
        "exampleString":"Hello",
        "exampleInt":"123"
      },
      "2":{
        "exampleString":"Bye",
        "exampleInt":"456"
      }
    },
    "02":{
      "1":{
        "exampleString":"Red",
        "exampleInt":"789"
      }
    }
  },
  "002":{
    "01":{
      "1":{
        "exampleString":"Orange",
        "exampleInt":"1212"
      }
    },
    "02":{
      "1":{
        "exampleString":"Green",
        "exampleInt":"2424"
      },
      "2":{
        "exampleString":"Pink",
        "exampleInt":"7878"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

in C# this is how I'm trying to lay out the nested dictionaries.
My main troubles with this are adding more than one "Middle Tier" to a single "Top Tier" dictionary Key.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TopTier
{
    // key is (000) level -- Value is (00) level
    [SerializeField] public SortedDictionary<string, MiddleTier> topToMiddle;
}


[System.Serializable]
public class MiddleTier
{
    // key is (00) level -- Value is (0) level
    [SerializeField] public SortedDictionary<string, BottomTier> middleToBottom;

}


[System.Serializable]
public class BottomTier
{
    // key is (0) level -- Value is BottomTierInfo
    [SerializeField] public SortedDictionary<string, BottomTierInfo> middleToBottom;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class BottomTierInfo
{
    public string exampleString;
    public int exampleInt;
}
```

Can something like this be fixed by making the Value of the TopTier dictionary an array holding multiple Middle Tiers? How would/could I go about doing that?

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to structure this for a while and I can't seem to make much sense of it so hopefully you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Is this JSON structure exactly what you need, or can you work with a slightly different JSON structure if it contains the same data (nested tiers with keys and values)?  The problem I see is that your tier keys (the 001, 01, 1, etc.) are property names in your JSON, but, in C#, I'd have them be property values, if that makes sense.

Comment: @RyanNigro I'm not 100% what you mean at the end there, but the main reason I'm trying to structure it like this is so the dictionary lookups dont have to search through every entry to get a value I want, just the entries on their "Tier" and below. But if what you're proposing is similar I'm all ears!

Comment: I'm not sure whether this works with the unity3d JSON serializer, but in .Net you could just do `public class RootObject { public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, BottomTierInfo>>> Data; }` without any of the intermediate classes, and it works.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/s0f3vS

Comment: Does it have to be Dictionaries at all instead of using Lists?

Comment: You can try to use [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/) to convert any json to a class structure in many languages. 
I ran it for you and it litterally spat out @dbc 's example. 
It's a really handy tool I use all the time when working with JSON.
//Edit: I also don't know if this works with the Unity serializer. But you can always use json.Net.